# Access python data path with ... (Ellipsis)

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to access a bool property in the python API to see if an option is enabled or not. The python tooltip for the option says this:

```
bpy.data.screens['Default']...show_grease_pencil
```

I try to use that in the console or in py scripts, and it says the ellipsis(...) is invalid syntax. What am I missing? (Ignore the tooltip text. I originally thought the '...' was just hiding some of the API). I tried it with double quotes and that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: I have to say this quirk really slows me down when I'm exploring new corners of the python API.  Just today I was up to my armpits in drivers and the tooltip just told me bpy.data.objects["Armature"]...type .  After a great deal of flailing about in the python console i was able to figure out that it was bpy.data.objects["Armature"].animation_data.drivers[0].driver.variables[0].type .  I look forward to the day when the tooltips save me an hour of fumbling in the dark.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a quirk of Blender's current UI, but actually you can deduce its location a bit, helped by Blender's [API documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

## Direct Access

The property you're looking for is [`SpaceView3D.show_grease_pencil`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_grease_pencil), that one is clear. Now, what class contains a [`Space`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Space.html) (`SpaceView3D`'s ancestor)? Scroll down to *References* section in that class' docs. One of references there leads to [`Area.spaces`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.spaces). This is easy, because one of its docs' *Reference* leads to [`Screen.areas`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Screen.html#bpy.types.Screen.areas), and `Screen` is the type of what's visible before the ellipsis. So the attribute's full path is:

```
bpy.data.screens['Default'].areas[X].spaces[Y].show_grease_pencil
```

... where `X` depends on the screen's subdivision, and `Y` is 0 if the 3D View is visible in that area. You can find that out from *Console*:

[image: 1a]

## Using `Context`

It's easier to read 3D View space's settings through `bpy.context`, e.g.:

- Use `bpy.context.space_data`, if the *3D View* area is active (i.e. accessed through an operator executed from the *3D View* itself).
- Use `bpy.context.area.spaces[1]`, if accessed through a *Console* whose display type is directly switched from a *3D View*.
- Use `bpy.context.screen.areas[X].spaces[0]` if accessed through a *Console* in another area, index `X` must be searched beforehand.

The same `show_grease_pencil` attribute is accessible through these different paths.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. It can be confusing since there is an operator called ... that I thought it was referencing somehow.