# How to set cursor location, pivot_point in script?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I am trying to set a cursor location and pivot point with

```
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.pivot_point='CURSOR'
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

and I see I am not doing it right. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See [Adhi's answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5356/12) as to why this won't work the way you are doing it.

> ## Using `Context`
>
> It's easier to read 3D View space's settings through `bpy.context`,
> e.g.:
>
> - Use `bpy.context.space_data`, if the *3D View* area is active (i.e. accessed through an operator executed from the *3D View* itself).
> - Use `bpy.context.area.spaces[1]`, if accessed through a *Console* whose display type is directly switched from a *3D View*.
> - Use `bpy.context.screen.areas[X].spaces[0]` if accessed through a *Console* in another area, index `X` must be searched beforehand.

What you want to use is

```
bpy.context.area.spaces[1].pivot_point='CURSOR'
bpy.context.area.spaces[1].cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

For the cursor location, there is a shorter alternative. All 3D View's cursor location is linked to the scene's, so it can also be accessed from `bpy.context.scene`:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

V2.8+ :

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: what worked for me was your third example

Comment: @dimus Do you mean that the others don't work or that way is better?

Comment: I ran it from text editor, and the third example worked -- I added a 'comment-answer' with the code: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5361/1311

Answer (score 6):

Here is a snippet of the code (forgive my bad python) which I ended up using after reading the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5360/1311)

```
import bpy

def areas_tuple():
    res = {}                                                               
    count = 0
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:                                  
        res[area.type] = count                                             
        count += 1
    return res  

areas = areas_tuple()
view3d = bpy.context.screen.areas[areas['VIEW_3D']].spaces[0]
view3d.pivot_point='CURSOR'
view3d.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on dimus' answer and the accepted one further:

```
def area_of_type(type_name):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == type_name:
            return area

def get_3d_view():
    return area_of_type('VIEW_3D').spaces[0]

view3d = get_3d_view()
view3d.pivot_point='CURSOR'
view3d.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Blender 2.80 this should be:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have zero or multiple number of view3d, the way to process this case is

```
view3ds = [area.spaces[0] for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if (area.type=="VIEW_3D")]
for view3d in view3ds:
    view3d.pivot_point='CURSOR'
    view3d.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

If you exactly know there is only one VIEW_3D by your eye, the way to process this case is

```
view3d = [area.spaces[0] for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if (area.type=="VIEW_3D")][0]
view3d.pivot_point='CURSOR'
view3d.cursor_location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

The idea to make this simple coding way is by python's magic.

```
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition]
```

This intuition of coding method can help you to process more complicated data with simple thinking and coding.