# Rotate object around cursor with Python

Tags: python

What Python command rotates an object around the 3D Cursor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume you already have the `Pivot Point` set to `3D Cursor` (although this could be done in Python also)

[image]

You can use the operator `bpy.ops.transform.rotate()`, but you need to override the context or else it will only rotate around the object's median point.

```
import bpy

def get_override(area_type, region_type):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
        if area.type == area_type:             
            for region in area.regions:                 
                if region.type == region_type:                    
                    override = {'area': area, 'region': region} 
                    return override
    #error message if the area or region wasn't found
    raise RuntimeError("Wasn't able to find", region_type," in area ", area_type,
                        "\n Make sure it's open while executing script.")


#we need to override the context of our operator    
override = get_override( 'VIEW_3D', 'WINDOW' )
#rotate about the X-axis by 45 degrees
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(override, value=6.283/8, axis=(1,0,0))
```