# Rotation around the cursor with low-level python (no bpy.ops)

Tags: python, scripting

In order to optimize my script, I would need some help to perform a rotation around the cursor
(see [Rotate object around cursor with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/rotate-object-around-cursor-with-python))

With low-level python, that means, without `bpy.ops.*` operations.

I have to admit that I didn't find a good overview on how to make rotation with python without `bpy.ops`. Do I have to perform matrix operations for a simple rotation around an axis Z located at the cursor position?

Comment: I think you are better of using the bpy.ops. The functions in the module call on compiled C commands. This is a lot faster than doing it with python. Also optimizing a script by not using the built-ins blender provides is rather silly. This is just my opinion though

Comment: The low level python api will call c-functions as well. [See this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators) and [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops) for reasons to not use operators.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Rotate a vector

```
import bpy
from math import pi
from mathutils import Vector, Euler, Matrix, Quaternion

v = Vector((1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
#point which will be rotated around the cursor

cursor_loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location

rot_mat = Matrix.Rotation(pi / 2.0, 3, 'Z')
v_new = rot_mat * (v - cursor_loc) + cursor_loc
```

There are further options available (see [api docs](https://www.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html)):

You can construct a matrix, *this is most efficient if you want to apply the same transformation on many points*.

```
mat = (Matrix.Translation(cursor_loc) *
       Matrix.Rotation(pi / 2.0, 4, 'Z') *
       Matrix.Translation(-cursor_loc))
v_new = mat * v
```

You can use quaternions:

```
# using (axis, angle) constructor
q = Quaternion((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), pi / 2.0)
v_new = q * (v - cursor_loc) + cursor_loc
```

or eulers:

```
eu = Euler((0.0, 0.0, pi / 2.0), 'XYZ')
v_new = v - cursor_loc
v_new.rotate(eu)  # works for quat's and matrix types too
v_new += cursor_loc
```

---

### Rotate an object

```
mat = (Matrix.Translation(cursor_loc) *
       Matrix.Rotation(pi / 2.0, 4, 'Z') *
       Matrix.Translation(-cursor_loc))

obj.matrix_world = mat * obj.matrix_world
```

`Euler` and `Quaternion` both offer a method to convert them to a matrix:

```
q  = Quaternion()
eu = Euler()

mat =  q.to_matrix().to_4x4()
mat = eu.to_matrix().to_4x4()
```

Comment: You can also do `from math import radians` and specify the rotation in degrees like `radians(90)` (equal to `pi/2`)

Comment: Thanks pink vertex for the answer. I have difficulties to adapt your proposal for a single point (the vector v) to a whole object obj; could you adapt your script to make it run for an object obj that is a plan or a cube? Thanks.

Comment: Added a section.

Comment: great, it helped me a lot! I used the matrix_basis and not matrix_world but your answer provided me the information I needed to move ahead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rotate object(s) around cursor with cursor rotation

I did a function. you can run it on selected objects in a loop.

```
for ob in context.selected.objects
    rot_around_curs(context, ob)
```

I convert cursor rotation to a matrix, then modify obj matrix to get a rotation around the cursor with the cursor rotation value

```
    def rot_around_curs(self, context, obj):
        curs = context.scene.cursor
        mat = curs.matrix
        loc = curs.location
        R = mat.to_quaternion().to_matrix().to_4x4() #cursor rotation
        T = Matrix.Translation(loc) #cursor location
        M = T @ R @ T.inverted() #we just involve the rotation
        obj.matrix_world = M @ obj.matrix_world #update obj matrix
```

the advantage of converting matrix in quaternion is to not use for instance curs.rotation_euler depending in what rotation mode you are

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the code. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)