# How can I add multiple points on a circle without changing its shape?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, workflow

I have created a circular curve and I'd like to add two points to it.

[image]

I know I can select two points and then hit subdivide to get a new point in between these two points, but that is not a very efficient way to create extra points as it will change the shape of the circle. I then have to move them to position, which requires quite a bit of work of adjusting all the handles and move the point itself.

Is there a way to create the desired point by clicking on the circle so it won't change the shape of the circle?

---

I have tried installing the *Curve Tools* add-on as suggested, but I still can't find a way to make it work for this purpose.

Comment: Perhaps the website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob has a tutorial on Curve Tools

Comment: There are a lot of super basic tools not present in Blender in version 1.0 (If that exsited)

Comment: OK, so I checked out the addon called Add Curves. It kinda works the way I wanted, but it still changes the shape of the circle after sliding out and placing the point in the specific position.

Comment: I have seen it work. Please see tutorial on youtube.  Bisecting  a bezier curve has been understood for probably 60+ years.  You should think .. I need a tutorial .. rather than the tool cannot do this.  Blender has a slide vertex ... for meshes which is quite convenient.  I do NOT know if the tool has a slide ... curve point.

Comment: https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Tools/tree/master/curve_edit_tools#curve-edit-tools - I grabbed it from here. As shown in the gif, it works perfectly for Beizier curve. The newly added point keeps the shape of the curve. But not for the circle. It just changes its shape by adding a new point.

Comment: On the tool menu .. panel .. you may need to [Filter] and select your desired choice ... I just had some .. unexpected and not delicious experience

Comment: if you select all, press V, switch to Aligned and subdivide, it won't deform the shape, is it what you're looking for? (but you can't create an additional vertex wherever you want, this is a limitation of bezier curve, you need to first subdivide and then move, which does change the shape)

Comment: @brockmann good find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Set the handle type to** ***Aligned***

*I should have read the question better, re subdividing, to have a new point remain on the circle to change the handle type.*

[image]

After adding the Bézier circle, select all in edit mode and *Control Points* → *Set Handle Type* → *Aligned* (Or only the two handles being sub'd.) The default Bézier curve has handle type 'AUTO' (look for a link to the handle type.)

After which the result of subdividing produces handles on the tangent.

[image]

*The active object is the default Bézier circle section subdivide, over the result above.*

For a circle, after adding a point as above, can then "point slide" it in its two original handle quadrants by rotating about the circle center pivot point and adjust the handle points to make a sine, cosine ratio.

The left-to-right handle length will be constant. The alignment after rotate will be correct. To keep as a circle is a matter of sliding handles. *For example*, it would be all horizontal right handle if rotated back to the top, and all vertical left handle clockwise to right original point...

It is somewhat reminiscent of the position in a slot of
*[How to do Trammel Of Archimedes Animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165190/how-to-do-trammel-of-archimedes-animation)*

About to add the handle fix to *[How to rotate bezier control point (viewport not updating)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159735/how-to-rotate-bezier-control-point-viewport-not-updating)* ...
However, for the answer to the question marked as a dupe has gone above and beyond - *[What is the fastest way to add vertices to a curve at a specific point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-add-vertices-to-a-curve-at-a-specific-point)*

Answer (score 3):

Curve Tools is addon . Menu Edit/User preferences. You can search by text and click the enable checkbox.  Blender 2.91

[image]

Subdivide and Multisubdivide are depicted above.

[image]

You may need to use the filter panel depicted above.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I turned on Curve Tools under Addon tab but it doesn't seem to work at all as when I shift A under curve menu, I don't see a bunch of new curve objects in the menu. Don't know what's going wrong here. What's the common reason for an addon not showing up?

Comment: Press the N or T keys to see panels open up.  Be in [<edit>] mode.  I am one person .. so maybe I am one guy .. American English .. maybe Dude .. Bloke? ... Perhaps the website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob with lots of videos .... has a tutorial on Curve Tools

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'm replying to all the above posts including yours...Haven't got used to the structure of stackexchange. Yes I'm pretty sure I'm in edit mode. By toggling N and T, I don't see Curve tools showing up anywhere. I'll dig into why it wasn't activated even I turned it on already. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Yeah I've got other addons turned on without a problem, but weirdly this Curve Tools simply doesn't work. According to what I see on several YTB tuts, I should have a bunch of new curve shapes available under the Curve menu when pressing shift A. Nope, still the same old 5 options.

Comment: @hiroober  ... please see edit

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I did it, but still no Curve Tools. Please see my screengrab in the edit above.

Comment: @hiroober Go into _Edit Mode_ and in the _N_ menu panel on the right go to _Edit_, there are some extra tools appearing when you enabled _Curve Tools_. When they are there, if you want to make sure that the shape of the circle is preserved you should use _Multi Subdivide_ even if you only want a single subdivision and enter a value your liking. This way the shape is (mostly) preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the Multi Subdivide working though I still don't have more options under Curve menu...Googling around now.

Comment: @hiroober If you feel I have answered the question please mark it as the answer. You can also mark the question with negative points if you like.