# Bezier curve spline point rotation using python script

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I'm currently to write a script which can arbitrarily create mesh from Bezier curve.
I used `bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.bezier_points`for finding spline points but their is no rotation variable. Then I find [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/python-store-rotation-normal-in-bezier-curve-point) post and used tilt value but nothing change. I even changed tilt interpolation.

EDIT: **I manually draw a curves with rotation and found in the python console all bezier points tilted rotation is zero.**

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159735/how-to-rotate-bezier-control-point-viewport-not-updating  There are a number of QAs re converting curve to mesh with python.  Please add code, or clarify point rotation and how it correlates to converting to mesh.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think either blender current version "bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.bezier_points[0].co.tilt" is not working like previous or I did something wrong. But I found also that when I created and modify bezier curve its not storing its rotation value in tilt variable. 

Now I have to try using matrix.