# How to rotate a selection of objects using blender python?

Tags: python, transforms

I want to rotate a collection of objects (example, two cubes) in Blender Python but without using `bpy.ops.transform.rotate` operation.

How may I go about doing that?

I'm not trying to rotate them individually, but rather rotate both of the cubes around one point, just as the `bpy.ops.transform.rotate` would.

Comment: Have you thought of making the objects children of an empty (keeping transforms) and then rotating the empty?

Comment: Probable Duplicate of  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/rotation-around-the-cursor-with-low-level-python-no-bpy-ops   Because the answer was written pre 2.8 see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect