# Blender script Python check the rotation is change, or active

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Hi im not a python master... im a really  noob.
Is possible determinate if a object rotation on pivot point and if false or true
assign a value for example 0-1 or 1-2?
i dont work  in game engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following python script will iterate through the "areas" in the current window to find 3D views and print what the pivot point is set to.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        print(area.spaces[0].pivot_point)
```

One thing I have noticed is that if you change the pivot_point in one 3D view it changes in any other 3D views you have open.  This leads me to suspect that the information exists elsewhere in another data structure, but I have not figured out where.

See also [How to set cursor location, pivot_point in script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5359/how-to-set-cursor-location-pivot-point-in-script)