# object.select_set(True) makes item active, not selected

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to add a simple triangle to a scene (with Blender demo BMW) using python script. I then want to enter edit mode, select a vertex and then move 3D cursor to that vertex, exit edit mode and then add an area light at the 3D cursor. Repeat to set up very basic three-point lighting. However, when I deselect all objects, and then try to select my "LightingRig" object using the code example, I can see that the triangle is active (not selected, as intended) and I get the following error:

*RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Context missing active object*

How can I set the triangle to be selected, and not active?[image]

```
import bpy
import os
import sys
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=os.path.join(lr_file_path, inner_path, lr_object_name),
    directory=os.path.join(lr_file_path, inner_path),
    filename=lr_object_name
)
lr = bpy.data.objects.get("LightingRig")

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

lr.select_set(state=True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT") # This is where the error occurs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 API, python, set active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/blender-2-8-api-python-set-active-object) Orange color means *selected*, you want an object to become yellow to be *active*.

Comment: I see. I thought orange was active. However, I'm still getting similar issues. 

I'm trying this:

bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()

bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

This gives similar context error:

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: This is because there's no 3D cursor inside the Text Editor where you run the script. You need to search for a view3d space to change the 3D cursor there, or do it like here: [How to set cursor location, pivot_point in script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5359/60486)

Comment: This can be done without using any operator I believe

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the suggested ideas. First time I've used python and also first time I've done scripting in Blender - there's a lot of quirks :)

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.